# Converting Date Columns in R ("character" into Date format)

Tags: r, dataframe, date, format, character

I have a sample date column as part of large data set, Below date is in multiple format.

I need convert below mentioned into Date format , Please help me with a solution.

22-04-2015
4/8/2015
18-04-2015
5/7/2015
26-05-2015
6/12/2015
24-06-2015
23-06-2015

Answer (score 1):

Try with `lubridate`. The function `guess_formats()` allows defining possible formats of your data (you could add others if needed), and then you can use `as.Date()` to get the dates in the proper class using the formats previously defined. Here the code:

```
library(lubridate)
#Dates
vecdate <- c('22-04-2015', '4/8/2015','18-04-2015','5/7/2015','26-05-2015',
             '6/12/2015','24-06-2015','23-06-2015')
#Formats
formats <- guess_formats(vecdate, c("dmY"))
dates <- as.Date(vecdate, format=formats)
```

Output:

```
dates
 [1] "2015-04-22" "2015-08-04" "2015-04-18" "2015-07-05" "2015-05-26" "2015-12-06" "2015-06-24"
 [8] "2015-06-23" "2015-04-22" "2015-08-04" "2015-04-18" "2015-07-05" "2015-05-26" "2015-12-06"
[15] "2015-06-24" "2015-06-23"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use R package *anytime* for date conversion?

```
> library(anytime)
> datemix <- c("22-04-2015", "4/8/2015", "18-04-2015", "5/7/2015")
> anydate(datemix)
[1] NA "2015-04-08" NA "2015-05-07"
```

You notice that the first and third character dates came up with NA. This is because the package *anytime* as currently defined does not include this format "d-m-y". It is very easy to add this format with the *addFormats()* command as shown below

```
> addFormats("%d-%m-%Y")
> datemix <- c("22-04-2015", "4/8/2015", "18-04-2015", "5/7/2015")
> anydate(datemix)
[1] "2015-04-22" "2015-04-08" "2015-04-18" "2015-05-07"
```

The output dates are converted into ISO format of YYYY-MM-DD.

You can explore all the formats in *anytime* using *getFormats()* command. Here is the link to the *anytime* on R CRAN https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/anytime/anytime.pdf